# VB6 Set Printer Orientation on Runtime not working on some Printers

Tags: vb6, report

I have a code to print data report on vb6, I use this to change the layout or the orientation of printer, it was working on my last printer EPSON L210 I think it has Ip address as Port, but on Printer Epson L120 it's a network printer.. when i use error handler to check the error it says subscript out of range.

```
Dim obj As PageSet.PrinterControl
Dim mPointer
Set obj = New PrinterControl
mPointer = Screen.MousePointer
Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass
DoEvents
If vOrientation = 1 Then
    Printer.Orientation = vbPRORLandscape
    obj.ChngOrientationLandscape
Else
    obj.ReSetOrientation 'This resets the printer to portrait.
End If
Screen.MousePointer = mPointer
DoEvents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now working, the network should be name to your computer, so I add a local printer instead so I can have full permission of the printer and updated the driver locally.